# JavaFX: update UI, but not from action on GUI, but information sent?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, listener

How can I change a JavaFX UI but not triggered by user gesture such as a button clicked, but triggered by an outside function (some data received) that calls a function that updates the UI?

I saw in a few questions here that task should resolve this issue, but I did not understand the below example completely:
I want to link (observer pattern) a kinesis consumer to fill color of a
circle in my GUI. I get that I need to bind the fill property of that circle
to consumed record event, but I did not understand what is: task.progressProperty()?
in the example code.
And to what I change it to, to get a link a record consumed to a circle fill?

Thanks!

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
        static final int max = 1000000;
        for (int i=1; i<=max; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
               break;
            }
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();
```

Comment: I am guessing this is a slim version of your other question. I think you should use `Timeline`. I would check the data from the server every second. If you receive some data, update the GUI. If not, do nothing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task

Comment: I am curious if these live charts update will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089022/line-chart-live-update. This simulates receiving live data and adding it to a chart using `AnimationTimer` Also https://levelup.gitconnected.com/realtime-charts-with-javafx-ed33c46b9c8d

Comment: Could you show what the data looks like that you will be receiving from the server? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530434/how-to-implement-a-worker-thread-that-will-process-kinesis-records-and-update-gu) post but I don't truly understand what the data will look like that you are getting from AWS.

Comment: You probably don't want a Task as you'd need to keep running it.  With no kinesis experience and just looking at your other post, it looks like you want to create a new interface `KinesisDataListener#onKinesisData` that you can pass into your consumer `new Consumer(database, trans, logic, listener)` which RecordProcessor will have access to.  Or you want to add it to your `consumeData(listener)` method. I have no idea which of those two places actually receives the data, but whichever one call `listener.onKinesisData(data)` which should call a RunLater(set circle color).

Comment: After finding something from you possible co-worker, could you post the `monitoringLogic.updateUI()` source?  It looks like the other guy says that's where it's trying to happen.